Is there a way to generate a train of gaussian pulses distanced by a certain PRT for a radar system?
I have a simulink block that contains a user-defined function that generates a single gaussian pulse. My objective is to generate multiple pulses distance by a certain PRT for a radar system. I tried few methods to make it generate multiple pulses but it didn't work. I would to like to have ur help please.
I tried to control the single gaussian pulse generator with a pulse generator whose the period is equal to the wanted PRT.

The gaussian pulse generator is inside the triggered subsystem.
.
Here is the code of the simulink block :
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function y = gaussian_pulse(t)

% Define Gaussian pulse parameters
fwhm = 1e-9; % Full width at half maximum (FWHM) in seconds
sigma = fwhm/(2.*sqrt(2.*log(2))); % Standard deviation in seconds


% Compute Gaussian pulse
y = exp(-(t.^2)/(2*sigma^2));

end 

